# How to properly sort characters alphabetically with mixed case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Given some word with mixed letters (both caps and small) which might also take white spaces (but not numbers or special characters), I want the output to be displayed as capital letters (all repetitions of a character if present) followed by small letters (all repetitions of a character if present).

The order of letters will be like `AAaaBBbbCCcc.....`

I have tried to do this using the `sorted` and `list.sort` built-ins.

```
word =  'hoLllLywOoDo'
sorted_list = sorted(word ,key = lambda s: s.capitalize())
print(''.join(sorted_list))
```

E.g., given `hoLllLywOoDo` I expect `DhLLllOooowy`. Instead, it returns `DhLllLoOoowy`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Why are you using `str.capitalize` for single characters instead of `str.upper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tuple inside your key function:

```
sorted_list = sorted(word ,key = lambda s: (s.upper(),s ))
```

The second param of the tuple will come in hand when the first param is identical: this will sort by uppercases letters first (sorting `'D'`and `'d'` the same), then sort by the letter (`'D'<'d'` - hence D comes first)

and you get:

```
DhLLllOooowy
```

`str.capitalize` is not needed, you are dealing with single letters anyway - capitalize is good for words to Start Wth A Capital Letter - you can use upper here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the capitalized letter as the key, `L` and `l` have the same key. But it seems like you want to sort by letter, then by capitalization. So, you should try having "two" keys by using a tuple like this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(word, key = lambda s: (s.capitalize(), s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.capitalize` means that the only consideration being taken when sorting is the uppercase version of the letter. So, to the sorting algorithm, `a` and `A` would be equal.

You can get around this by telling it to use both the captialized version, and it's actual version as the key

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(word, key=lambda c: (c.capitalize(), c)))
'DhLLllOooowy'
```